# How to find elements in array that share duplicate attributes

Tags: ruby

I have an array of players. Each player has been assigned a `score_value`. I want to find players that tied.

The array is `@@players_list`, which has an unknown number of players.

I tried:

```
@@players_list = [player1, player2, player3]

tied = @@Players_.list.find_all {|p| p.win_value.to_s.count(p.win_value.to_s) > 1}
```

This does not return an error, but also does not identify the duplicate score values

```
tied = @@players_list.select {|p| array{|p| p.score_value}.count(p.score_value) > 1}.uniq
```

This returns:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
..._value}.count(p.win_value) > 1}.uniq
```

Comment: An example array would be useful. Also desired output.

Comment: Try `array.group_by(&:score_value)`. This will get you 90% there.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error then that needs to be fixed first otherwise your question is off-topic. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sergio Tulentsev for getting me 90% there.  Here's what I came up with that seems to work.

```
group_by_win_value =  @@players_list.group_by(&:win_value)
group_by_win_value.each do |key, value|
    @tied_players = []
    if value.count > 1
        puts "the following players are tied"
        value.each do |player|
            puts player.name``
            @tied_players << player
        end
    end
end
```